# changing the background of a button

Tags: button, configuration

this method is used in a project it 's supposed to show all the layouts of the project in a list and when you click to one of them it shows you its  buttons and when you click to one of those buttons it diplays all the drawable in res and then the part where i need your help: when you clik to one of those drawable it have to show the layout you choosed with a new  background(the drawable you cliked) for the button you choosed

```
public void myclass{
        Class<drawable> cls = R.drawable.class;
        fieldlist = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        setContentView(layoutIds[position]);
        allButtonsInLayout = getViewsFromViewGroup(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Button.class);
        //allButtonsInLayout = getViewsFromViewGroup(findViewById(android.R.id.content), Button.class);
        //String tabname=allButtonsInLayout.get(position).getResources().getResourceEntryName(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + allButtonsInLayout.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int size=allButtonsInLayout.size();

        String[] tab_s = new String [size];
            cls = R.drawable.class;
        fieldlist = cls.getDeclaredFields();


        for (java.lang.reflect.Field fld : fieldlist) {
            int i=0;
            for(    i=0;i<allButtonsInLayout.size();i++){

                try {
                                        setContentView(R.layout.listallbuttons);
                    final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewallbuttons);
                    drawableId = fld .getInt(null);
                    String s = fld.getName();
                    Log.v("tagllll", "msg" + s);
                                     if((k<=i)) {

                        tab_s[k++]=s;
                    }
                    else{
                        size++;

                        String[]temp=new String[size];

                        for (int f=0;f<tab_s.length;f++){
                            temp[f]=tab_s[f];

                        }
                        tab_s=temp;

                        tab_s[k++]=s;

                    }

            for (int k1=0;k1<tab_s.length;k1++){
                     //int j=allButtonsInLayout.size();

                      if (k1%allButtonsInLayout.size()!=0){
                      tab_s[k1]="null";


                      }

                  }
                     ArrayList<String> wordList = convertStringArrayToArraylist(tab_s);
                     int jk=0;
                    while ( jk<size){
                     wordList.remove("null");
                     jk++;
                     }

                    drawableId--;
                    allButtonsInLayout.get(i).setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,wordList);

                    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                                     **that's the part where i am lost i need to show the chosen layout with the clicked button with a new background(the one i choosed**

                                  }

                    });

                                  }
                catch(Exception e){

                    e.getMessage();

                }


            }


        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

i needed just to make final the variable position

listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

```
                        @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int arg2, long arg3) {

    **setContentView(layoutid[position]**

                                      }

                        });
```